# Can I reject a call from the iPhone SDK

Tags: iphone, phone-call

I want my app to automatically reject a call when it comes in. Is this possible with the iPhone SDK?

Comment: He is watching you: http://radipad.com/attachments/ipad-general-discussion/63-ipad-name-steve_jobs_angry-jpg

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, it's not. Third-party apps don't get to interfere with core functions of the phone.

Answer (score 0):

Steve wont let you do that.